# Why do I get an undefined function error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to delete data from my DB with AJAX. I have a list of questions and they are sorted into a table. Every row in the table has a hyperlink which I use as a button, and these delete buttons have an id which is the same id that this is given question has in the database. These delete buttons belong to a class named 'delete_btn'. 
In the 'loadDeleteButtons' function I am trying to iterate through this array, and give every delete button an onclick event, which would eventually call the 'deleteData' fuction. This function should delete the given question by using the delete button's 'ID' and should delete it with an async query.
I get this error:

```
Uncaught Typerror: undefined is not a function
```

This error points to the 'obj.getAttribute('id')' part. Thanks in advance!

```
var loadData = function(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReadQuestionList.php?bottom=' + limit.bottom + '&number=' + limit.number,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            obj.html(html);
            setTableWidth(false);
            deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete_btn');
            loadDeleteButtons();
        }
    });
};

var loadDeleteButtons = function(){
    for(var obj in deleteButtons){
        deleteButtons[obj].onclick = deleteData(obj);
    }
};

var deleteData = function(obj){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReadQuestionList.php?id=' + obj.getAttribute('id'),
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            setTableWidth(false);
            loadData(questionTable);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You can also check your console, it will tell you the line

Comment: `deleteButtons[obj].onclick = deleteData(obj);` doesn't do what you think it does. That being said, the error you are receiving is a moot point. The error is the result of this line of code. You're essentially doing `deleteObj(0)`, and `0` clearly doesn't have a getAttribute property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code causes `deleteButtons` to be an **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)**:

```
deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete_btn');
```

This code traverses every object of that collection.  Assuming there is only one button with that class, the collection's objects would be `0`, `length`, `item`, and `namedItem`:

```
for(var obj in deleteButtons){
  deleteButtons[obj].onclick = deleteData(obj);
}
```

None of those objects have a `getAttribute` property, causing this line to fail:

```
url: 'ReadQuestionList.php?id=' + obj.getAttribute('id')
```

Instead, do this:

```
for(var obj = 0 ; obj < deleteButtons.length ; obj++) {
  deleteButtons[obj].onclick = function() {
    deleteData(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very close, but not quite. The problem is within the for loop in your second snippet, `obj` is a key. On the first iteration, the key is `0`, and deleteData(0) clearly won't work because `0` doesn't have a `getAttribute` property. The solution you included though will fix it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of lines using undefined variables:

```
    for(var obj in deleteButtons){
```

`deleteButtons` is outside the scope of `loadDeleteButtons()`. Add `var deleteButtons;` at the very top to solve this.

```
loadData(questionTable);
```

`questionTable` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I disagree with the first mention, because `deleteButtons` was defined as a global variable containing a collection of elements. The second i would consider insignificant, likely just something left out of the demo.

Comment: deleteButtons is in global scope as well as questionTable

Answer (score -1):

Since `deleteButtons` is defined in a ajax callback it may not be loaded when declaring `loadDeleteButtons`.

A better solution is to use jQuery.on to delegate event handlers.

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete_btn', function(){
    deleteData($(this));
});
```